# Does cycles or prorender use combined Ryzen 2700 & Vega 56 capabilities?

Tags: opencl

Ryzen 7 and Vega 56 uses OpenCl.

Does cycles or amd prorender uses those opencl capabilities combined or do you need to choose gpu or cpu rendering.

I amasking that because i saw in benchmarking that those two are similar in results. So if they aredo not using combined capabilities i could save some money.